# Python PML neural network used to approximate function always results in the training set mean values

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm studying neural networks and i'm trying to develop a simple perceptron multilayer neural network to aproximate a function using python.

The problem is that the neural network returns the mean value of the training set for every input. I've been looking the code for days trying to find out what is wrong but i can't see it.

Could some one shed a light on this?

Thank you in advance!

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
class pmc_3_layers:
    
    def __init__(self, n1, n2, n3):
        # Number of elements in each layer
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.n3 = n3
        
        # Inicializing weights with randon values (LeCun)
        self.w = []
        self.w.append(np.random.default_rng().uniform(-(2.4/n1), (2.4/n1),(n2, n1+1)))
        self.w.append(np.random.default_rng().uniform(-(2.4/n1), (2.4/n1),(n3, n2+1)))
    
    def forward(self, variables_updated):
        
        # Sigmoid function
        gfunc = np.vectorize(lambda a : 1/(1+np.exp(-a)))
        
        # First layer
        i1 = self.w[0]@variables_updated
        
        y1 = gfunc(i1)
        
        y1 = np.insert(y1, 0, -1, axis = 0)
        
        # Second layer
        i2 = self.w[1]@y1
        
        y2 = gfunc(i2)
        
        return i1, y1, i2, y2
        
    def backward(self, variable, classe, i1, y1, i2, y2):
        
        # Sigmoid function derivate
        glinhafunc = np.vectorize(lambda a : np.exp(-a)/((1+np.exp(-a))**2))
        
        # Second layer
        glinha2 = glinhafunc(i2)
        
        grad2 = (classe - y2)*glinha2
        
        if y1.ndim <= 1:
            self.w[1] = self.w[1] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad2@y1.reshape(1, -1)
            
        else:
            self.w[1] = self.w[1] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad2@y1.T
        
        # First layer
        glinha1 = glinhafunc(i1)
        
        if glinha1.ndim<=1:
            grad1 = -glinha1.reshape(-1,1)@grad2*self.w[1][:, 1:]
        else:
            grad1 = -glinha1.T@grad2*self.w[1][:, 1:]
        
        if grad1.ndim<=1:
            self.w[0] = self.w[0] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad1.reshape(-1,1)@variable.reshape(1, -1)
            
        else:
            self.w[0] = self.w[0] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad1.T@variable.reshape(1, -1)
        
    
    def eqm(self):
        
        eqm = 0
            
        for i in range(len(self.variables_updated)):
            
            i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(self.variables_updated[i])
        
            for j in range(self.n3):
                eqm = eqm - (((self.output[j] - y2[j])**2)/2)
            
        eqm = eqm/len(self.variables_updated)
        
        return eqm
        
    def train(self, variables, output, taxa_aprendizado, precision):
        
        self.output = output
        self.variables = variables
        self.variables_updated = np.insert(self.variables, 0, np.full((1, len(self.variables)), -1), axis = 1)
        self.taxa_aprendizado = taxa_aprendizado
        self.precision = precision
        
        self.epoch = 1
        
        print('The inicial weight matrices are:')
        print(self.w)
        print('\n')
        
        while True:
            
            print('\n')
            print('######################################')
            print('Starting a new epohc number %i' %(self.epoch))
            print('\n')
            
            previous_eqm = self.eqm()
            
            for i in range(len(self.variables_updated)):
                
                i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(self.variables_updated[i])
                
                self.backward(self.variables_updated[i], output[i], i1, y1, i2, y2)
            
            current_eqm = self.eqm()
            
            self.current_eqm = current_eqm
            
            if (abs(current_eqm - previous_eqm) <= precision):
                print("Training finished in %s epochs" % (self.epoch))
                print('\n')
                print("The final eqm was %f" % (self.current_eqm))
                print('\n')
                print('The final weight matrices are:')
                print(self.w)
                break
            
            self.epoch = self.epoch + 1

    def predict(self, variables):
    
        variables_updated = np.insert(variables, 0, np.full((1, len(variables)), -1), axis = 1)
        
        resultados = np.zeros((len(variables_updated), self.n3))
        
        for i in range(len(variables_updated)):
                
            i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(variables_updated[i])
            
            for j in range(len(y2)):
                
                resultados[i][j] = y2[j]
        
        return resultados
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes and the code now works:

```
class pmc_3_layers:
    
    def __init__(self, n1, n2, n3):
        # Number of elements in each layer
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
        self.n3 = n3
        
        # Inicializing weights with randon values (LeCun)
        self.w = []
        self.w.append(np.random.default_rng().uniform(-(2.4/n1), (2.4/n1),(n2, n1+1)))
        self.w.append(np.random.default_rng().uniform(-(2.4/n1), (2.4/n1),(n3, n2+1)))
    
    def forward(self, variables_updated):
        
        # Sigmoid function
        gfunc = np.vectorize(lambda a : 1/(1+np.exp(-a)))
        
        # First layer
        
        i1 = np.atleast_2d(self.w[0]@variables_updated)
        
        y1 = np.atleast_2d(gfunc(i1))
        
        y1 = np.insert(y1, 0, -1, axis = 1)
        
        # Second layer

        i2 = np.atleast_2d(self.w[1]@y1.T)      

        y2 = np.atleast_2d(gfunc(i2))
        
        return i1, y1, i2, y2
        
    def backward(self, variable, classe, i1, y1, i2, y2):
        
        variable = np.atleast_2d(variable)
        classe = np.atleast_2d(classe)
        
        # Sigmoid function derivate
        glinhafunc = np.vectorize(lambda a : np.exp(-a)/((1+np.exp(-a))**2))
        
        # Second layer
        
        glinha2 = np.atleast_2d(glinhafunc(i2))

        grad2 = np.atleast_2d((classe.T - y2)*glinha2)
        
        self.w[1] = np.atleast_2d(self.w[1] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad2@y1)
        
        # First layer
        
        glinha1 = np.atleast_2d(glinhafunc(i1))
        
        
        grad1 = np.atleast_2d((grad2.T@self.w[1][:, 1:])*glinha1)
        
        self.w[0] = np.atleast_2d(self.w[0] + self.taxa_aprendizado*grad1.T@variable)
        
    def eqm(self):
        
        eqm = 0
            
        for i in range(len(self.variables_updated)):
            
            i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(self.variables_updated[i])
        
            eqm = eqm - (((self.output[i] - y2)**2)/2).sum()
            
        eqm = eqm/len(self.variables_updated)
        
        return eqm
        
    def train(self, variables, output, taxa_aprendizado, precision):
        
        self.output = output
        self.variables = variables
        self.variables_updated = np.insert(self.variables, 0, np.full((1, len(self.variables)), -1), axis = 1)
        self.taxa_aprendizado = taxa_aprendizado
        self.precision = precision
        
        self.epoch = 1
        
        print('The inicial weight matrices are:')
        print(self.w)
        print('\n')
        
        while True:
            
            if (self.epoch==1)|((self.epoch%100)==0):
                print('\n')
                print('######################################')
                print('Starting a new epoch number %i' %(self.epoch))
                print('\n')
            
            previous_eqm = self.eqm()
            
            for i in range(len(self.variables_updated)):
                
                i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(self.variables_updated[i])
                
                self.backward(self.variables_updated[i], output[i], i1, y1, i2, y2)
            
            current_eqm = self.eqm()
            
            self.current_eqm = current_eqm
            
            if (self.epoch==1)|((self.epoch%100)==0):
                print('EQM difference:')
                print(current_eqm - previous_eqm)
                
            if (abs(current_eqm - previous_eqm) <= precision):
                print("Training finished in %s epochs" % (self.epoch))
                print('\n')
                print("The final eqm was %f" % (self.current_eqm))
                print('\n')
                print('The final weight matrices are:')
                print(self.w)
                break
            
            self.epoch = self.epoch + 1

    def predict(self, variables):
    
        variables_updated = np.insert(variables, 0, np.full((1, len(variables)), -1), axis = 1)
        
        resultados = np.zeros((len(variables_updated), self.n3))
        
        for i in range(len(variables_updated)):
                
            i1, y1, i2, y2 = self.forward(variables_updated[i])
            
            for j in range(len(y2)):
                
                resultados[i][j] = y2[j]
        
        return resultados
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, well done! Can you please mark your answer as accepted? This helps keeping our beloved Stackoverflow of high quality :) 
Also, it's more useful to only include the parts that changed in your answer, that makes it more readable for future readers!